# ASP.NET JQuery .click() not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, click, internet-explorer-11

The following .click()-method is fired in Chrome without problems.
In Internet Explorer it is only fired if I refresh the page (F5). If I access the page by entering the url (or redirected by a buttonclick from an other page) the .click-method is NOT fired.

But if I put an alert("?") before the .click() it works in IE too!

Why does it not work correctly in IE? I can't let the alert() be there...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Fake click on the last used Tab
    alert("?");
    $("#"+GetCookie("lastTab["+window.location.pathname+"]")).click();
});
```

=> The available (clickable) tabs are created in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
...
});
```

**EDIT From comments:**

They are created inside the `.read(function($)` in this way:

```
$("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#Tab' + upperIndex + '" id="TabHead' + upperIndex + '" onclick="SetCookie(this.id);">' + title + '</a></li>').after('<div id="Tab' + upperIndex + '"></div>');
```

After Container is created after the script:

```
<div id="tabsContainer"><ul id="HillbillyTabs"></ul></div>
```

Comment: My guess is the DOM isn't loaded when the event is binded - so the `alert` stalls long enough that the DOM loads, and the event binds.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.

But if I put the .click() into the 
>>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   << (which indicates the DOM is ready?)
it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: How are the elements you're trying to click generated?

Comment: i deleted my post since this is more likely to be some kind of mistake in the code, you can show more of the "orginal" code here

Comment: They are created insite the .read(function($) in this way:

$("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#Tab'+upperIndex+'" id="TabHead'+upperIndex+'" onclick="SetCookie(this.id);">'+
    title+'</a></li>').after('<div id="Tab'+upperIndex+'"></div>');

The Container is created after the script:

</script>
<div id="tabsContainer"><ul id="HillbillyTabs"></ul></div>


Bad view of the code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to inject the function call, but rather add an event listener to the code. For example: (I made up some variables as your code did not indicate some things here)

```
var upperIndex = $('#tabsContainer').find('ul').length;
var title = "mytitle";
var newHeadId = 'TabHead' + upperIndex;
var newTabId = 'Tab' + upperIndex;

$("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#' + newTabId + '" id="' + newHeadId + '">' + title + '</a></li>').after('<div id="' + newTabId + '"></div>');

$("#HillbillyTabs").on('click', '#' + newHeadId, function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  SetCookie(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems IE does not recognize :

```
$(window).load()
```

You could try :

```
window.onload = function() {
     $("#"+GetCookie("lastTab["+window.location.pathname+"]")).click();
};
```

Comment: Sadly it's exact the same problem with this way.

In original code I got one more statement after the .click().
Its a fadeIn() and it works without problems - so IE is recognizing it (but not the .click before).

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

Curiously the fadeIn in the .load doesn't work for IE too (like the .click)

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Fake click on the last used Tab
    alert("?");
    $("#"+GetCookie("lastTab["+window.location.pathname+"]")).click();
    // When the page has loaded in Chrome
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain").fadeIn(0);
});
```

For fading in I had to put the method immediately after the creation-method for the tabs (inside the .ready()) instead of the end of .ready().

There is now also the .click and it works now for IE.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    setTimeout(function() {
        ...
        //Creation of tabs
        $("#tabsContainer").tabs();
        //Fake click on the last used Tab
        $("#"+GetCookie("lastTab["+window.location.pathname+"]")).click();
        // When the page has loaded in IE
        $("#contentBox").fadeIn(0);
    }, 0); 
//.click NOT here
});
```

Thanks for your fast responses and tips!

Kind regards

Comment: Adding a "timeout" is an artificial method that simply says "delay some"; you should use a more definitive approach;